# Proving that matrix $A$ is a scalar matrix if $C^{-1} A C$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been stuck with this question:

> Given $A \in M_{n\times n} (\mathbb F)$ and $\forall C \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb F) , C \; \text{is invertible} \; \rightarrow \; C^{-1}AC \; \text{is diagonal}, \text{prove that } \exists \lambda\in\mathbb {F} : A = \lambda I_n$

Now here is what I suggested:

> $C^{-1}AC$ is diagonaizble so $\exists P, P \; \text{is invertible} \rightarrow C^{-1}AC = PDP^{-1} \rightarrow A = CPDP^{-1}C^{-1}$. And now we mark $K = CP$, and so: $A = KDP^{-1}C^{-1}$. Then we note that $K = CP$ is invertible because $C, P$ are invertible, so their multiplication $CP = K$ is invertible, and also $P^{-1}C^{-1}$ is invertible.
>   Now we know that $D$ is a scalar matrix, and therefor $A$ is also a scalar matrix.

I am pretty sure what I did has a major flaw in it, but I can't think of any other way!

Comment: You don't know that $D$ is a scalar matrix, just that it is diagonal.

Comment: But if $A$ is diagonalizable then so is any conjugate of $A$, so the statement is not correct.

Comment: Oh, yes indeed Matt.
user1551, I wasn't the one who wrote the question, my professors are...

Comment: I'm very sorry. It is given that $C^{-1}AC$ is diagonal!

Comment: It seems that an additional assumption was omitted, the assumption of "to have exactly one eigenvalue".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hypothesis imply that **every** vector is an eigenvector for $A$.  Now, if $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$, you can show that $v+w$ will be an eigenvector of $A$ if and only if $\lambda=\mu$.  Together, these facts imply that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are the same.  Hence $A$ is a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: +1 Much simpler than my idea with the center of group of invertible matrices. Nice.

Comment: Can you please explain further why the hypothesis imply that every vector is an eigenvector for A?

Comment: The matrix $C^{-1} A C$ is diagonal if and only if the columns of $C$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Oh.
The only thing I still can't figure out, is why that if $v+w$ is an eigenvector of A then $\lambda = meu$?

Comment: Well, if $v + w$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $\lambda v + \mu w = A(v+w) = \rho(v+w) = \rho v + \rho w$ for some $\rho$.  If $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent (i.e. neither is a scalar multiple of the other), then this implies that $\lambda = \rho = \mu$.

Comment: I understand.
Last thing: If all eigenvalues of A are the same then A is a multiple of the identity matrix.
Proof?

Comment: I think it's a good idea for you to try to see this yourself.  It follows quite quickly from the idea of diagonalization.

Answer (score 0):

Something looks odd to me. If $A$ is any diagonalizable matrix, then $A=P^{-1}DP$ and hence for all $C$ we have $C^{-1}AC=(PD)^{-1}DPD$ is diagonalizable. But $A$ might not be diagonal.

Are you sure the problem doesn't say $C^{-1}AC$ is a **diagonal** matrix?Then I think it is true.

Comment: Wow, I'm VERY sorry.
It does say that $C^{-1}AC$ is $diagonal$